# EasyadminBundle : Remove some field (createdAt)

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin

I would like to remove some fields like createAt in the crud Admin from EasyAdminBundle.

I think I can use the fields I want (code below). But is there a way to remove some fields, and include all others.

> ```
> public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
> {
>     return [
>         IdField::new('id'),
>         TextField::new('Nom'),
>         TextEditorField::new('description'),
>     ];
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the fields and exclude these you don't want like this:

```
    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
     {
        yield TextField::new('taskitemtext', 'Task');
        yield NumberField::new('flag', 'Flag');
        yield BooleanField::new('isdone', 'Done?');
        yield DateTimeField::new('date', 'Deadline')->setFormTypeOptions([
            'html5' => false,
            'widget' => 'single_text',
        ]);
```

this will show only those that are listed.

Comment: Of course ! Yield :) Thanks,